# Probability that sums of $N(0,1)$ variables exceeds 5

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution

I'm trying to work out what is the probability that a process $W(t) = \sum_{i = 1}^t N(0,1)$ ever exceeds 5 before reaching a certain number of steps (say 100). So my thinking is that the probability that $W(1)$ is less than 5 is:

- $P(W(1) < 5) = \Phi_{0,1}(5)$ where $\Phi_{0,1}$ is the CDF of a normal distribution with $\mu = 0, \sigma^2 = 1$

the probability that $W(2)$ is less than 5 is:

- $P(W(2) < 5) = \Phi_{0,2}(5)$

and so on until the probability that $W(100)$ is less than 5 is $\Phi_{0,100}(5)$. For the process to never exceed 5, all the $W(t)$ from $t=1$ to $100$ need to be less than five, so the probability that $W(t)$ never exceeds 5 in the first 100 steps should be

$P(W(1) < 5) \times P(W(2) < 5) \times ... P(W(100) < 5) \approx \Phi_{0,1}(5) \times \Phi_{0,2} (5) \times ... \Phi_{0,100}(5) \approx 0.9999 \times 0.9997 \times ... 0.691 \approx 0 $

So it says that the process is guaranteed to reach 5, which is not correct based on some simulations. What am I missing here?

Comment: $W(1),W(2),...$ are not independent.

Comment: I personally do not see a way out but brute force calculation. Perhaps some inclusion and exclusion will help. If it was a poisson process(that is W(n) was a sum of n iid $Exp(\lambda)$ variates then it could have been easily done. $N(0,100)$ would just be $Poi(100\lambda)$ variate. Even if these were sum of positive random variables it would have been easy. But all these said, the problem with your work is that you have assumed independence and made it a product. This is not true.

Comment: yes, thanks. I see that now. You're right. I don't no how to proceed either. But I do feel like the problem isn't impossible. It's just 'what is the probability that $W(t)$ exceeds 5 on or before 100 steps.

Comment: I think is independent attempts. So it is probably possible to use the distribution of the sum of 't' random quantities with N (0,1). 

 For T = 100: N (μ, σ²) = N (100*0,100*1) = N(0,100) 

 I would say it won't be a problem.